# Batch Job Completes Without Updating Values - Formula Field in WHERE clause

Tags: apex, batch, schedulebatch

I have the batch job below that is running and completing successfully, but not updating any records. When I run the query in the query editor I get 135 results, so there are records that need to get picked up. I have a feeling that the issue is due to the order of execution in the batch job involving the Formula Field.

I have the Formula field (`Valid_Quota_Realignment_TEST__c`) because I need to compare the values of the `OwnerId` and `User__c` fields with the `Sales_Desk_Primary_Owner_ID__c` that are referenced in the SOQL Query.

The formula in the Formula field is:

```
OR(User__c != Sales_Desk_Primary_Owner_ID__c, OwnerId != Sales_Desk_Primary_Owner_ID__c)
```

Is the formula field my issue? Is there a better way to do the comparison of the values within the SOQL query for the batch job?

**Batch Job Code:**

```
    global class BatchQuotaRealign implements Database.Batchable<Sobject>
{
    global Database.Querylocator start(Database.Batchablecontext BC)
    {       

        return Database.getQueryLocator([SELECT Id,OwnerId,Sales_Desk_Primary_Owner_ID__c,User__c FROM Quota__c WHERE Quota_Type__C = 'desk quota' AND Sales_Desk__r.Primary_User__r.IsActive = true  AND Valid_Quota_Realignment_TEST__c = true
]);


    }

    global void execute(Database.Batchablecontext BC, list<Quota__c> scope)
    {
        list<Quota__c> DeskQuotasToBeUpdated = new list<Quota__c>();
        for(Quota__c qu : scope)
        {
            //Quota__c qu = ((Quota__c)ca);
            qu.User__c = qu.Sales_Desk_Primary_Owner_ID__c;
            qu.OwnerId = qu.Sales_Desk_Primary_Owner_ID__c;
            DeskQuotasToBeUpdated.add(qu);
        }

         System.debug('Desk Quotas To Be Updated List: ' + DeskQuotasToBeUpdated);

         Database.update(DeskQuotasToBeUpdated,false);

    }


    global void finish (Database.Batchablecontext BC)
    {
        System.debug('Batch Quota Realign completed successfully!');
    }
}
```

**Batch Job Schedulable Class:**

```
global class BatchQuotaRealignSchedulable implements Schedulable
{
   global void execute(SchedulableContext sc)
   {
        // the argument has to be a class that implements Database.Batchable<Sobject>
        Id batchProcessId = Database.ExecuteBatch(new BatchQuotaRealign());
   }

}
```

Comment: Odds are, it's a validation error. I see you're using Database.update(records, false), which means that you're ignoring any errors; it's probable that those 135 rows aren't be updated because of an error. What errors do you get if you change it to Database.update(records, true) instead?

Comment: @sfdcfox Thank you, it looks like that was the issue.